# How private is my private mapping in a deployed smart contract?

Tags: mapping, solidity, smartcontracts

Is it possible for anyone to see the data that is stored inside a private mapping in a deployed contract? And does that also apply for private variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Everything is visible. All you are controlling is how functions can be called.

[For reference](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters):

- `public`: Can be called from anywhere.
- `private`: Can be called from within the contract, but not subcontracts.
- `interanl`: Can be called from within the contract and from subcontracts.
- `external`: Can be called from another contract but not within the contract itself.

If the data itself needs to be private, you have to encrypt it on the client side and decrypt after retrieval (this will create problems if you need to actually use the data in a transaction), or you need to use a private blockchain.

Comment: So there is no way I can sell a piece of information (along with the token) that is stored inside the contract because everybody can see it anyways?

Comment: Not if the commodity is the data itself. But, you can store a reference to the data that is stored elsewhere while still using the blockchain for the purchasing transaction. You receive payment while the buyer has proof off purchase (which can be used to retrieve the information later and/or multiple times).

Comment: But if the reference is e.g. a link to the download location it's pointless again because everybody could read it without paying, right?